# Create a database entry for the UID after sign up with firebase and swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I’m developing an app in swift by using firebase in the back end.

I have successfully created a user by using the standard procedure as stated in the documentation.

My problem comes when I want to add the UID value to the database. I can’t. What I’m doing is getting the UID (userID) from the Auth().user (what I successfully do) and using the following code (I don’t have de computer do it can contain errors but I copy it from the documentation and I’m fact it compiles, the problem is that is does nothing

```
let ref = Database().database().reference()
self.ref.child(“users”).setValue(userID)
```

I have tried with the following

```
Self.ref.child(“users”).child(user.id).setValue(userID)
```

But it fails due to the fact that users have no children. The issue is that users is a collection and I don’t now if it works in the same way or not.

My intentions is to create the entry in the “users” collection in the database just after singing up a new user. (And to be able to layer erase it)

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the [minimal, complete/standalone code that anyone of us can run to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Right now there are things that you describe having done (and assume having done correctly), which we can't verify. That makes it hard to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase has two NoSQL databases:

1. the Realtime Database, which is the original JSON database.
2. Cloud Firestore, which is the newer document/collection database.

These two databases are both part of Firebase, but have completely separate APIs.

You speak about *collections* in your question, which are a Cloud Firestore concept. But your code uses the API of the Realtime Database. If you're looking to write data to Cloud Firestore, you'll want to use the API that is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data).

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot! These solve part of the issue, never the less I don't know how to create a new entry with the userId I obtained before. I have tried with the db.collection("users").addDocument(data:.....) but I down think is the right way since I don't want to add any data. I want so set the id of the document the same as the user id to get direct access to it later

Comment: I notice that maybe the solution is just to create a new document adding the name and the initial data and it will be done

Comment: A document doesn't exist unless there data in it. So you might just want to add the UID itself to the document for now. Also note that it's best to name the documents after their UID, so instead of using `add()` use `db.collection("users").document(uid).setData([
    "uid": uid])`.

Comment: Ehh we just coordinated! This is what I will try. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Hi again. I don't know why but it doesn't work. I used the following db.collection("users").document(firebaseUseriD).setData(docData) { error in
            if let error = error{
                print ("Error:  \(error)")
            }
        }                                                                                                                                         it doesn't fail in execution time but when I goes to the firebase database no new document is created

Comment: It was an issue with the security rules of the database. Now it is working fine. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Good to hear you found the problem. 

Comment: Would you be so kind to help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60829957/unable-to-fetch-information-of-a-document-in-firebase-firestore-using-swift

Comment: In fact I still have the same problem. I can create it but only from the view controller where I perform the sign up